# retrieving user information from auth component

Tags: cakephp

I have problems checking if user is logged in from any controller other than UsersController.

I was trying to make a user profile page. I routed it to PagesController and when I use

```
$this->Auth->user()
```

it always returns null. But if I route it to UsersController it works fine. Why is that? Login seems to work ok.

Answer (score 1):

Your app_controller.php :

```
class AppController extends Controller {

    var $components = array('Auth', 'Session', 'Cookie');

    function beforeFilter() {
        $this->Auth->authError = 'blabla';
        $this->Auth->loginError = 'blabla';
    }

}
```

In your controllers :

```
function beforeFilter() {
    parent::beforeFilter();
    $this->Auth->allow('function1', 'function2', 'function3'); //etc
    $this->Auth->autoRedirect = true;
}
```

Comment: what's autoRedirect for? otherwise it's basically what i do. Except i didn't add cookies, not sure if it's important

Comment: autoRedirect : to redirect user after login on the page where he came

Answer (score 0):

It's because you include the Auth component only in your User's controller. You should include it in AppController and in beforeFilter(). This way you will have access in all controllers.

Comment: No it's not that. It is included into the AppController plus I think it'd throw errors if i tried to access it without including.